# How can add latitude and longitude in onesignal segment editor

Tags: node.js, curl, onesignal

I need help regarding one signal REST API, I am not able to access location in curl in command and I do not know how to put multiple locations through code.

Please let me know if you have any answers.
[segment editor look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUhMl.png)

Comment: was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 0):

fill `filters` parameter with location data [see this](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#send-to-users-based-on-filters)

```
curl --include --request POST  \
--header "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"  \
--header "Authorization: Basic YOUR_REST_API_KEY"  \
--data-binary "{\"name\": \"SEGMENT_NAME\", \"filters\": [{\"field\": \"session_count\", \"relation\": \">\", \"value\": \"1\"},{\"operator\": \"OR\"},{\"field\": \"tag\", \"key\": \"TAG_KEY\", \"relation\": \"exists\"},{\"operator\": \"OR\"},{\"field\": \"last_session\", \"relation\": \"<\", \"value\": \"1\"}]}" \
https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/segments
```

[see also these examples](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-notification#example-code---create-notification)